# Unity 5 Client RPC call: Failed to Invoke ClientRpc

Tags: c#, networking, unity, unity-networking

I have a Unity 5 client and server running. On the server a path is generated and I want the client to receive the position of each target node on this path. Following the Client RPC calls section here http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html I have created the following script:

```
public class AccessingTargetPos : NetworkBehaviour {


[ClientRpc]
void RpcPosFromServerToGoTo(Vector3 pos)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Going to ... " + pos);
}


public void PrintPath(Vector3 pos)
{
    if (isServer) 
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log (pos);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Send Pos ...");
        RpcPosFromServerToGoTo (pos);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Sent!!");

    } 
}


}
```

Both the client and the server have this script, assigned to a game object. However with the above I receive the following in my console:

[image]

At the moment all I want is for the client to output the positions received. When I get this I'll move on. I have followed the link, where have I went wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem here was not reading the RPC calls section of http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html properly. "They can be sent from any server object with a NetworkIdentity that has been spawned." When I had the client object reading in the locations become a spawned object under Registered Spawnable Prefabs (under Spawn Info, under Network Manager Script from Unity 5) then the RPC was called. I was calling the RPC on a static object before hand, throwing up the errors seen above.